# customize registerController in spring security UI

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm going to use spring security UI for forgot password and reset password.
In my User domain I have :

```
String firstName
String lastName
String emailAddress 
String password 
String password2
```

user login with emailAddres instead of userName. I've already update my config.groovy with grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'emailAddress'

How can I customize registerController in spring security UI?

Answer (score 2):

You should customize controller:

Here [Spring Security UI Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/single.html#customization) (please read documentation).

With this command `grails s2ui-override register`, you will customize this files:

- controller/RegisterController.groovy
- views/register/forgotPassword.gsp
- views/register/index.gsp
- views/register/resetPassword.gsp

Here: [views/register/index.gsp](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/views/register/index.gsp) you can see the code of view, you should add your new input fields here, and, at the end of [RegisterController](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ui/RegisterController.groovy) you can customize `RegisterCommand` to create new users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had read the documents before I asked this question. I read it again but still can't solve my problem. as you see I don't have username property in my user class so I get hibernate exception: could not resolve property: groovy of: com.example.core.User

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Login with email/password instead of username/password ?

Comment: Please open a new question like "Login with custom fields with Spring Security Core Plugin"